# Generating GraphQL json document from Flask graphene

Tags: flask-graphql

I want to generate a GraphQL .json document that has graphene schema from Flask. Django has something like manage.py that does this (https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/blob/master/docs/introspection.rst). Anyone know how to generate a GraphQL .json doc from graphene schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, seems like this is what I was looking for https://graphql.org/learn/introspection/.

I can use schema endpoint to get the documentation of any graphene server api.